# How to edit keyboard macro saved in file?

Tags: text-editing, keyboard-macros

Here is my custom keyboard macro:

```lisp
(fset 'gen-numbers
      (lambda (&optional arg)
        "Keyboard macro."
        (interactive "p")
        (kmacro-exec-ring-item
          (quote ([134217848 107 109 97 99 114 111
                   45 105 110 115 101 tab return return]
                  0
                  "%d"))
          arg)))
```

I saved it to a file.
But after some time I want to edit it. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked in the Emacs manual? `C-h i g(emacs)Edit Keyboard Macro`.

Comment: @NickD: Consider posting that as an answer. The question is reasonable, and Emacs has an answer for it (you pointed to it).

Comment: @Drew: sorry, I haven't had time to do anything other than posting hit-and-run comments. Please feel free (you or anybody else) to provide proper answers: I'm hoping that the comments (incomplete as they are) might point the OP to a quick resolution, but they certainly are not proper answers (which take much more time, at least for me). Waiting for me to answer it is probably hopeless at this point.

Comment: @NickD: Maybe the OP will add (and perhaps accept) the answer.